# When I lose access to my Exchange server, is there a way to keep my contacts?

Tags: email, exchange, file-transfer

Changing jobs and will soon no longer have access to my company's Exchange server.  Contacts are in Exchange and synched on my Droid (HTC EVO) using the default Exchange app.  I want to be sure I don't lose my contacts when I no longer have access to the Exchange server.  But if I transfer them to GMail contacts now, I'm concerned it will duplicate my contact records.  Any suggestions or tips?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You may want just transfer your Exchange contacts to GMail. There are quite good duplicate/merging tools in GMail Contacts. Use `More actions` and `Find and merge duplicates`. There are automatic as well as manual merging modes.

You can import CSV formatted contacts into GMail from its `More actions` and `Import` menu.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using Outlook when you're at a PC in the office, you could just Export your contacts from Outlook on your last day, and then Import them into GMail.

GMail is good at handling CSV imports from Outlook, and will also suggest Duplicates that can be merged and help you to merge them.

A few helpful links:

[Export Outlook Contacts to Google Gmail (Outlook 2002/2003)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/export-outlook-contacts-to-google-gmail-HA001148902.aspx)

[Transfer contacts between Outlook and Google Gmail (Outlook 2007)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/transfer-contacts-between-outlook-and-google-gmail-HA010222048.aspx)

[Export contacts (Outlook 2010)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/export-contacts-HA101870639.aspx) then follow the final steps from either of the above guides for the GMail import stage

[Merging duplicate contacts in GMail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=165334)

Answer (score 0):

If it's stock, and you don't see an "export" option, you're probably toast.

I know CyanogenMod allows contact export to SD Card in VCF format, at least in version 6 (don't know about 7, don't run it). CM4 did not allow contact export.

I can't imagine a system administrator allowing rooted phones on their network.

Comment: Thanks to you both for replying.  Found the export/import function and was able to export to SD and then import back to GMail contacts. I'll just have some dupes on the Droid until my last day at work is done.  It was much easier than I expected - the import/export function on the device worked surprisingly well!

Comment: Oh so that's Stock? Awesome.